# How to Add and Store the Result in x86 Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86, as88

My teacher gave our class this to do. We have to add x and y together and store it in f. Everything that the teacher has taught us and posted hasn't helped at all. I can't even ask other people in my class for help because they don't have a clue either. Please help.

```
! 8088 Add Values
_EXIT = 1

.SECT .TEXT
start: ! Label at start (optional)

! Instruction/Code Section

exit: ! Label at exit (optional)
PUSH _EXIT
SYS

.SECT .DATA
! Data declarations and initializations
x:
.BYTE 5
y:
.BYTE 6
f:
.BYTE 0 

.SECT .BSS

! Following .SECT .BSS an empty line
```

I honestly tried a bunch of mov commands but I know that it's not even close to being correct.

Comment: Near duplicate of [Add two variables in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35646173), but use a byte register (AL).  Like in [How can I add two bytes in Assembly if the sum of these two bytes exceeds a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64306828) for adding bytes.

Comment: [How to Add and Multiply then Store the Result in x86 Assembly Language using AS88](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74649523) seems to be a repost of this also asking for multiply.  Same phrasing in the question so it's probably the same user on a different account.